# AutoCompleteTextView showDropDown is not working

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-8.0-oreo

In AutoCompleteTextView, On focusChangeListener() showDropDown is not working only in Android Oreo devices and showing the error message **"android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token android.os.BinderProxy@f2a625f is not valid; is your activity running ?"**

```
googlePlaceAutocompleteAdapter = new googlePlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this,list);

search_place.setAdapter(googlePlaceAutocompleteAdapter);

search_place.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                    search_place.showDropDown();
            }
        }
      });
```

search_place is my autoCompleteTextView and I am attaching googlePlaceAutoCompleteAdapter. The list contains places which I want to display before the user enters any text.

Comment: is this working below oreo device? can you share code

Comment: Yes it is working fine devices below oreo.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Please put some code in the question

Comment: I have updated the question with my code